# Request for hint: The FLAMES game

Tags: number-theory

The game is the following.

Take the word FLAMES. It has 6 letters. Choose a number, say 9. Then strike off the letters in FLAMES by cylcilcally counting in steps of 9 letters. So we get the following succession of letters as we proceed to strike off letters (I have put the stricken letter in braces).

1. FL(A)MES
2. (F)L(A)MES
3. (F)(L)(A)MES
4. (F)(L)(A)ME(S)
5. (F)(L)(A)(M)E(S)

The last letter remaining is E. The question is if we are given the number of letters in the word like 6 in our case and if we are given the step size, is there a way to right away tell as to which letter remains in the end? In our case, E remained.

My observations are:

1. Let the step size be x (9 in the above example). Let n be the number of letters in the word (6 in the example). Then we get a series of mod equations

x=x_n mod(n)
 =x_n-1 mod(n-1)
 =x_n-2 mod(n-2)
 .
 .
 .

These residues basically decide what will be the next letter to get stricken off

2. If x=n*q+x_n, then x_n-1 and x_n differ by q unless x is a multiple of n-1.

Beyond this, I fail to proceed. This is similar to "The Josephus Problem" but what is going on in here is different. I request you to please give me a hint so that I can proceed to figure out the answer. I wish to do this for a general case where I am given only the numbers 'x' and 'n'.

Comment: I don't see how this is different from the Josephus Problem.

Comment: @KSmarts: In the classic telling of the Josephus problem the number is $2$.  TryingHard:  the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josephus_problem) in effect just suggests doing the counting when the number is greater than $2$.

Comment: @RossMillikan Thanks a lot for the quick response!